# How do I autocorrect latitude, longitude and altitude values inputs?

Tags: flutter, controller, textfield

Please help me solve this problem.
I need a handler for user input latitude, longitude and altitude values. Values must be positive or negative numbers and can be separated by a period and a comma. In this case, `,` is automatically replaced with `.`
How can I prevent the user from entering letters and other symbols other than numbers and `.`, `-`, `,` ?
More than one character `.`, `-`, `,`?
So that if a number begins with `.` or `,`, was `0` automatically inserted in front?
The `-` sign can only be the very first character and not allow entry elsewhere?
When entering more than one character `0` at the beginning, replace with one `0.`?

```dart
  var lat = TextEditingController();
  var lon = TextEditingController();
  var height = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    lat.addListener(_convertCommaToDot);
    lon.addListener(_convertCommaToDot);
    height.addListener(_convertCommaToDot);
  }

  void _convertCommaToDot() {
    _convertCommaToDotForController(lat);
    _convertCommaToDotForController(lon);
    _convertCommaToDotForController(height);
  }

  void _convertCommaToDotForController(TextEditingController controller) {
    String text = controller.text.trim();
    
    text.replaceAll(',', '.');
    
    if (text.startsWith('.')) {
      text = '0' + text;
    } else if (text.startsWith('-.')) {
      text = '-0' + text.substring(1);
    }
    if (text.startsWith('--')) {
      text = text.replaceFirst('--', '-');
    }
    
    if (text.startsWith('00')) {
      text = '0';
    }

    if (text.isEmpty) {
      text = '0';
    }
    
    // ??????
  }

  void Function(String newtext) onchanged(TextEditingController controller) {
    GeoPoint? point;
    return (newtext) {
      point = GeoPoint(
              lat: double.parse(lat.text)!,
              lon: double.parse(lon.text),
              height: double.parse(height.text))
    };
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    lat.dispose();
    lon.dispose();
    height.dispose();
    name.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
              keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                  signed: true, decimal: true),
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                    RegExp(r'^[+-]?(\d+|(\d*\.,\d*))$')),
              ],
              onChanged: onchanged,
              controller: controller,
```

I need help adding logic to provide for all options for erroneous input of coordinates without displaying error warnings, but with automatic error correction.
Also, I'm not sure I wrote it correctly RegExp.
Many thanks for any of your help.

Comment: I think you are bit over-engineering this. How about you start with writing down all cases, then how they should look fixed and then derive steps you need to take?